# After plugin options changed hook

Tags: plugins, cron

i am looking for a hook that fires after the options for my plugin have changed.

I have an option named "interval", it basically registers a cron schedule. Now, id like the change to take effect, right after the option is changed.

What hook can i hook in to for that? This is my settings page

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'apd_create_menu' );

function apd_create_menu() {

    add_menu_page('APD Plugin Settings', 'APD Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'apd_settings_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__));
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_apd_settings' );
}

function register_apd_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'apd-settings-group', 'directory' );
    register_setting( 'apd-settings-group', 'interval_time' );
    register_setting( 'apd-settings-group', 'interval_posts' );
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
add_filter( 'update_option_apd-settings-group', 'run_after_change', 10, 2 );

function run_after_change( $old_value, $new_value )
{
    echo $new_value . '<br>';
    echo $old_value;
    die();
}
```

Does not seem to have any effect when added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the action `update_option_{$option}`, where `$option` is the same as the second argument for `register_setting()`. This hook fires after the option has been updated.

```
add_filter( 'update_option_directory', 'run_after_change', 10, 2 );

function run_after_change( $old_value, $new_value )
{
    // compare both values and do something
}
```

`10` is the priority, `2` the number of accepted arguments for the callback function.

The opposite is `pre_update_option_$option`, which runs before the option is updated. It sends the same two parameters.

Comment: The values 10, and 2 are just dummy values i asume. Sorry dont really get it, is this hook fired after options are updated or ?

Comment: @IvanRistic See my update.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: @IvanRistic Sorry, I messed this up. It is the *second* parameter from `register_setting()`. See my update again. :)

Comment: since 4.4.0 there is also $option after $old_value and $new_value.